# In a value object, why use specific property set and get methods?

Tags: php, design-patterns

In looking at a [value-object](https://github.com/antimattr/common-address/blob/master/src/AntiMattr/Common/Address/GenericAddress.php) pattern, I notice most use separate get and set property functions, which are both boring to write and provide lots of opportunities for typo errors.

Is there a reason for writing in this style, rather than a generic get/set routine? This is the boilerplate I am using:

```
class ValueObject{
    protected $property1;
    protected $property2;
    protected $property3;

    public function get( $propname ){
        if( property_exists( "ValueObject", $propname ) ){
            return $this->$propname;
        }
    }

    public function set( $propname, $value ){
        if( property_exists( "ValueObject", $propname ) ){
            return( $this->$propname = $value );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use PHPDoc to describe the types of your properties this way. If you don't want to write getters/setters (a good IDE can autogenerate them for you), implement `__get` and `__set` and use `@property` documentation blocks to describe the properties.

Comment: Wouldn't you document the property where it is declared (using the [@type](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md)) rather than in a get/set?

Comment: Sure, you should do that, but even with that annotation your IDE will not be able to figure out the type returned by `$VO->get('property1')` (unless that IDE has special logic to detect this kind of access, which I would not bet on).

Comment: Good point. Now to find a way to ask the question of which IDE could autogenerate the get/set...

Comment: A lot of the reason has to do with encapsulation and making sure that your properties aren't accidentally modified by outside code. Getter and setters are the _end to the means_ that help facilitate working with those properties outside the class.  One reason you would opt for getters/setters is if you need to do some type of processing to the data before it is set or retrieved.

Comment: @Amgine: I'm partial to [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). It can generate getters/setters and has a really powerful code analyzer, among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind getters and setters is quite interesting.

Let's assume we have a user object with a username, first name and last name and age, something like this

```
class User()
{
public $username = 'special!';
public $firstname= 'johnny';
public $lastname = 'frecko';
public $age = 55;
}
```

Everything is fine, and assuming we create a new object inside the `$user` variable, we can happily call `$user->age` to get and set the name.

Now, later down the line, you decided that for a special reason, you want to set the age of the user based on a formula, the formula depends on the age of the user itself!

In our little drill, The age of the user is his actual age minus the amount of length of his name!

You can't modify the other methods in your program, They're all wired together, you can't make a new instance variable without rewriting everything, so what do you do?

You write a getter from the 'get-go'. Something like

```
function getAge()
{
    return $this->age;
}
```

It's trivial, and boring to write. But now if we need to fix the age variable for our entire program, the solution is as simple as adding some code to the getter :

```
function getAge()
{
    return $this->age - strlen($this->firstname);
}
```

We do not need to rewrite anything actually, only this tiny piece of code. 
The reason you write getters and setters BEFORE you even realize you need them is because we humans are terrible at planning ahead, and this gives you an excellent window to add some more unplanned code further down the line.

Comment: This raised all kinds of questions for me, about balancing the cost of future flexibility with the risk of developer errors in writing many setters, getters, and all the unit tests. Abstracting the model method for changing the age from the method for getting the age would allow storing the modified age instead of recalculating it every time the user logs in, and could be a part of the change firstname method. Maintainability vs. bugginess. Normally I don't edit with an IDE, but this project (a CRUD) has a lot more value objects and is making me reconsider my development environment.

Comment: I think the developer errors are non-existent because it's really just a superb practice to have. I write setters and getters for everything because it saves me days of work 4 months into the project, when we realize an attribute needs some validation before setting it and things like that. Also note that saving the 'modified age' into an instance variable forces you to re-write your entire API, you now need to access that new variable and not the old 'age' variable.

Comment: We will have to disagree. For a specific class, this added at least 10 lines of code, 16 lines of documentation, and a variable number of lines of test code for each property of the class. Developer errors **did** occur. It **may** save time in four months, but don't ignore the real costs it does have.

Comment: It just never had any real cost. You should always program for six months from now anyway